# default callback function in wp_list_comments

Tags: comments, callbacks

Which default callback function wp_list_comments use if I don't set callback parameter? I saw in the code of this function but I can't understand it.

Answer (score 5):

The `wp_list_comments()` function uses the HTML comment list class `Walker_Comment` by default:

- A single *comment* is then displayed with the `Walker_Comment::comment()` method ([#source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1779)).
- If the comment format is *HTML5* then the `Walker_Comment::html5_comment()` is used instead ([#source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1831)).
- The *pingbacks* are rendered with the `Walker_Comment::ping()` method ([#source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1757)).